# How can I accsess to register user list from android device? (without personal hoasting)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hello I want to accsess authenticated user from android device to check if my users contact have any account in my list or not. Recently I have no any host and just use of the firebase console thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with the help of [Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/). Assuming you are using [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/), to verify if a user exists, you just need to create a new node in your database named `usersEmail`. Every time a user wants to sign-in, add his/her email address there. Your database should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    ---- usersEmail
       |
       ---- john@email,com: true
       |
       ---- mary@email.com: true
       |
       ---- mark@email.com: true
       |
       //and so on
```

In order to verify, just use `exists()` method on the reference like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userEmailDatabaseReference = rootRef.child("usersEmail").child(particularUserEmail);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            Log.d("TAG", "User does not exist!");
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "User exists!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
userEmailDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

In which `particularUserEmail` is the email address you want to verify if exists.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't have any server-side in single just consol how can I use the first part of the code in database?

Comment: You have added `Android` as a tag to your question, so my answer was to achieve what you want programmatically. Regarding the console, there is no seach future, you can search manually through the database but it will be a little bit harder. So i strongly recommend you writing some code.

Comment: No unfortunately

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Excuse me what?

Comment: In which point of the above algorithm have you stoped? What error do you get?

Comment: i cant get the list of users in fire base

Comment: I don't know how do it.

Comment: Then post another fresh question regarding your last problem. If you think that my answer helped you in any way, please consider accepting it. Thanks!